# Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException at ArrayAdapter<String>

Tags: java, android, mysql, spinner, android-arrayadapter

I have two buttons that execute the same method to populate its own Spinners with data from Mysql database, but the problem is that only one Spinner is been populated, and when I click the another "Buscar"(From portuguese: "Search") button I got "java.lang.NullPointerException" and the application aborts.

My Code

This is the first button, this code works and populates the spinner:

```
    btnBuscarProduto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        buscarPor = "produtos";
                        System.out.println("Buscando por: "+buscarPor);
                        Looper.prepare();
                        resultadoBusca = buscar(edtBuscaProduto.getText().toString());
                        System.out.println("Resultado da busca: "+resultadoBusca);
                        ((Activity)context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                if(resultadoBusca.equalsIgnoreCase("vazio")){
                                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Nada Encontrado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                    toast.show(); 
                                 }else{
                                   listaBusca = makeList(resultadoBusca);
                                   ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, listaBusca);
                                   spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                                   spnProdutos.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
                                }               
                            }});

                    }
                  }).start();                 
            }
        });
```

This is the second button, this code works but doesn't populates the spinner:

```
    btnBuscarPizza.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        buscarPor = "pizzas";
                        System.out.println("Buscando por: "+buscarPor);
                        Looper.prepare();
                        resultadoBusca = buscar(edtBuscaPizza.getText().toString());
                        System.out.println("Resultado da busca: "+resultadoBusca);
                        ((Activity)context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                if(resultadoBusca.equalsIgnoreCase("vazio")){
                                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Nada Encontrado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                    toast.show(); 
                                }else{
                                    listaBusca = makeList(resultadoBusca);
                                    System.out.println("Lista da busca: "+listaBusca);
                                    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, listaBusca);
                                    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                                    spnPizzas.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
                                }               
                            }});

                    }
                  }).start(); 
            }
        });
```

In the method above the error is in these lines:

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, listaBusca);
                                        spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                                        spnPizzas.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

Other methods:

```
    public String buscar(String termo){
        String resp = null; 
        try{
                httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.101/android/busca.php");
                nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("buscarPor", buscarPor));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("busca", termo)); 
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));            
                response=httpclient.execute(httppost);           
                ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                resp = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
            }catch(Exception e){
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Erro: "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show(); 
            }
        return resp;
    }

    public List<String> makeList(String input){ 
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        String[] newArray = input.split("\\|");
        for (int i =0; i<newArray.length; i++){
            list.add(newArray[i].toString());
        }   
        return list;
    }
```

Comment: post your LogCat. that tells you where the NPE is.

Comment: where is `context` initialized? where is the spinner initialized?

Comment: 11-09 13:53:51.676: I/System.out(1331): Resultado da busca: Calabresa|
11-09 13:53:51.676: I/System.out(1331): Lista da busca: [Calabresa]
11-09 13:53:51.676: I/System.out(1331): Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-09 14:06:18.410: I/dalvikvm(1331): Jit: resizing JitTable from 512 to 1024

Comment: @RenanOliveira you cannot update ui from a thread. you are displaying toast in `buscar`. This has nothing to do with the exception however

Comment: I managed to fix the problem, the problem was that my declaration was with a name diferent of my code, and eclipse isn't accusing error.